# Can i show more than 4 columns in a related list in partner community record screen?

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, partner-communities

I have a record detail page which has related lists in it. But my related list just shows 4 column in the community screens.
Do we have something similar to enhanced lists for community screens ?

Comment: It should show all columns once you click on the related list. Also, you must be using 2:1 ratio page in community.

Comment: On clicking of related list it shows all but the enhanced lists concept doesnt work in community screen. It still shows only 4